# Host silverlight 3.0 in wpf application

Tags: wpf, silverlight-3.0

How do I go about hosting a silverlight 3.0 application inside of a wpf application in which I can pass data between the two? It needs to run without internet connectivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a project I'm working on to do that.  It's very experimental right now...Hell I really haven't even announced it yet.

http://silverlightviewport.codeplex.com

-Jer

Comment: Does this viewport provide a way of communicating between the the XAP and WPF application?

Answer (score -1):

There is no known control that can do this seamlessly out there as yet. To do something like this, you will need to host a web control and use javascript to communicate with the host for interop. Which by the way is not at all recommended.